# Hiding status bar on iPad scaled mode pushes window down

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, statusbar

When I call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:hideStatusBar];
```

on a iPad running an iPhone app on scaled mode, the status bar doesn't even hide. Instead, a 20 pixel black space gets pushed onto the top of my iPad views; ultimately getting my app rejected by apple even though I don't want anyone using this 'iPhone only' app on an iPad.

If I remove the setStatusBarHidden call, the iPhone obviously doesn't hide the status bar. On the iPad running scaled mode, the black bar doesn't show up anymore.

View controller-based status bar appearance is set to NO.

I have also tried the following:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
  return hideStatusBar;
}
```

and this set before I need to hide the status bar.

```
hideStatusBar = YES; //changes
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

However, "prefersStatusBarHidden" isn't called. I just need a solution so that the black bar doesn't appear on the iPad scaled mode and the status bar disappears on the actual iPhone.

I'm running this on iOS 8 and 9.

Comment: And I prefer not to add code to detect that the app is running in compatibility/scaled mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, in addition to the code you've got, you have to create the Info Plist BOOL item `View Controller Status Bar Appearance` (also called `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`) and set it to YES.

The code that works for me is:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:NO];

    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
...
```